# Test if active document in Rstudio is RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudioapi

I want to add a small function to my `RStudio` AddIn which extracts all chunks from an `Rmarkdown` document, does some transformation and displays it as new editor window in `RStudio`. Basically, that will be a thin wrapper around `knitr::purl`. The function will eventually be called via the AddIns interface in `RStudio` and should consider the currently opened editor window as input.

What I was wondering though, is how to include a check whether the current editor window shows indeed an `RMarkdown` document.

I could use the file extension like this:

```r
if (grepl("\\.Rmd$", rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path)) {
   ## Rmarkdown -> do knitr::purl
} else {
   ## No Rmarkdown -> give a warning
}
```

But this feels hackish and a new `Rmarkdown` document, which is not saved yet (and opened via `File -> New File -> RMarkdown...`) will fail this check.

As `RStudio` itself does somehow recognize whether a file is meant to be an `Rmarkdown` document (creating a file as highlighted will add the `Knit` button for example, even if it not saved yet), I was wondering how I would ultimately find out the "file" type of an editor window?

I skimmed through the [Admin Guide Appendix](https://docs.posit.co/ide/server-pro/reference/rstudio_ide_commands.html) hoping to find a function like `isRMarkdown` to be called via `rstudioApi::executeCommand` but to no avail.

What would be a reliable way to check the file type associated to the current editor window in `RStudio`?